# Sending Photo via UI Send Dialog

Tags: facebook, dialog, photo, send

I am trying to open a Send UI Dialog linking to the link property of a graph API photo object, however I'm receiving the following error:

> **property values must be strings or objects with a 'text' and a 'href' attribute**

The Javascript code I'm using is as follows:

```
FB.ui({
  method: "send",
  display: "popup",
  link: photo.link
});
```

It works if I set the name parameter, however it doesn't include an image or description from the linked page. If I try to include an image of the photo, I receive the following error:

> **FBCDN image is not allowed in stream**

Is there any sane way of sharing a photo uploaded to Facebook using the Send Dialog?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This appears to be a limitation imposed by Facebook.

From [this post](http://www.syndicatedmethods.com/SyndicatedBlogs/post/2010/06/22/FBCDN-image-is-not-allowed-in-stream-How-can-this-be.aspx):

> Serving Images in Stream Stories
>
> Jun 18, 2010 3:21pm
>
> We no longer allow stream stories to contain images that are hosted on the fbcdn.net domain. The images associated with these URLs aren't always optimized for stream stories and occasionally resulted in errors, leading to a poor user experience. Make sure your stream attachments don't reference images with this domain. You should host the images locally.